# Getting this error "ORA-06413: Connection not open"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, oracle10g

I am using visual studio 2010 and Oracle 10g. Operating system: Windows 7 home basic. If I use the following code in visual studio 2005, I am getting a correct output. But in Visual Studio 2010 I get an error

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.OracleClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("uid=scott;pwd=tiger;data source=");
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    OracleDataReader dr;
    string name1, pass1;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmd = new OracleCommand("Select* from tb1 where name='" + TextBox1.Text + "'and pass='"+TextBox2.Text + "'", con);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            name1 = dr[0].ToString();
            pass1 = dr[1].ToString();
        }
        if (name1 == TextBox1.Text && pass1 == TextBox2.Text)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect user name or password");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean its happening on the same machine ? Are you able to connect via sqlplus or any other tool ?

Comment: your connections string does not contain any reference to the Oracle server !

Comment: Ah yes I did not see the connection being added it was not on my screen.

Comment: I would check that the connection is open first before executing in that case. Take out the connection open in the page load then in the button click method add.

Comment: You need to reply in comments instead of editing the question.

Comment: @Bill lizard..Thank you..I am new to stackoverflow..Here after will reply in comments..

Comment: @Yashvanth Thank you.  One last note, when you're editing an answer there's an orange question mark (?) at the top right of the input box.  You can click on that to get tips on formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a problem with the `tnsnames.ora`, where your connection is defined.

You can omit `tnsnames.ora` with this connection string:

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = !!!!!!!!YOURDBNAME!!!!!!!!!)(SERVER = DEDICATED))); User Id=Scott;Password=tiger;");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not assigned the connection to the command, you need something like below before you execute the command:

```
cmd.Connection = con;
```

Comment: that's not it - in `Button1_Click` the OP creates a new `OracleCommand` with a `con`!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the connection open from the page load and add the following before the execute:

```
if(con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
        con.Open();
}

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please search your hard drive for a file named `tnsnames.ora`, and post the contents of the file here.

And some tips:

- The con object will instanciated and opened every time the page loads.
- A button click forces a page load and a page load event too. See "[General Page Life-Cycle Stages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)".
- Move the code to the button-clíck Handler.
- MessageBox is always shown on the server, a user from a client will never see this message. When you develop the server and client are on the same physical machine.
- Add a div to your `default2.aspx`.

and call:

```
error.InnerText="Incorrect user name or password";
```

Check name and password twice, one time in the SQL statement, and one time in the code. This is better:

```
dr.Read(); 
    If (dr.HasRows())
        Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
    else
        error.InnerText="Incorrect user name or password";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable tips..I posted the contents of the file above..please look at it..Thank u..

Answer (score 0):

VS 2010:
i would like to share anexperience, when i was pooling oracel connection via WCF service and hosting that WCF on development server. getting that error "ORA-06413: Connection not open". could not find actual help for web serach. Finally, i deployed the compiled version of WCF on production server. when i used that WCF service from my application it worked for me....

Hope this could help someone facing the same issue...